# Android - Eclipse Screen capture code

Tags: android

I'd like to know if I can take a screenshot of my phone and save it in my gallery. Like the printscreen function on Windows, is there anything like that for Android? Is there any code to print the screen of my application?

Answer (score 2):

These are the possible way to doing it.

- If you want to take screenshot of emulator or connected device in eclipse, then

> Open the Android view "devices" (under Window --> Show View --> Other... --> Android --> Devices). Click on the device or emulator that you want to take a screen shot of, then click the "Screen Capture" button and save it wherever you want.

- If you want to screenshot of your app programmatically then follow the answers here : [How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android)
  Here some tricks that use shell commands needs your phone to be rooted.

  Here is the sample code from above link.

  ```
  // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
  String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "img_name.jpg";   

  // create bitmap screen capture
  Bitmap bitmap;
  View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
  v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
  bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
  v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

  OutputStream fout = null;
  Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mPath)); //can used as uri

  try {
      fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
      fout.flush();
      fout.close();    
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```
- And as @Shobhit says you can take screenshot by manufacturer shortcuts if available. here is the some reference if you need: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-ways-to-take-screenshots-on-android/

Comment: Thanks, I was only looking for this. So I can only test it on a rooted android device right?

Comment: @user2610342: this can also work on unrooted device except some.

Comment: @user2610342: please mark it as accepted if you find your answer here, it will help other users. Any upvote will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to do it programatically or manually. When you say `like PrintScreen in Windows, I assume that you want to take a screenshot manually. You can use different combination of buttons in different phone models, which come with Android OS. [How to take screenshots on Android](http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-take-screenshots-android-177316/) blog lists various ways you can take a screenshot in different model of android phones. Hope this helps.